# Copy recently modified files from one directory to another

Tags: beginner, bash

I am new to bash scripting. Could you please give a review of this code that copies recently modified files from one directory to another in bash? The main commands are in my `bash_aliases` file.

### Main code

```
#!/bin/bash
# Aliases file

cpRecent(){
    . ./helperlib.sh
    __processoptions $@
    if (( $? == 0 ));then
        __getrecentfiles
        __processlines
        local numOfCopiedFiles=0
        for line in "${!filelist[@]}"; do
            cp $line ${filelist[$line]}
            (( ++numOfCopiedFiles ))
        done
        echo "You have copied $numOfCopiedFiles file(s)"
        unset files
        unset filelist
    fi
    return
}

mvRecent(){
    . ./helperlib.sh
    __processoptions $@
    if (( $? == 0 )); then
        __getrecentfiles
        __processlines
        local numOfMovedFiles=0
        for line in "${!filelist[@]}"; do
            mv $line ${filelist[$line]}
            (( ++numOfMovedFiles ))
        done
        echo "You have copied $numOfMovedFiles files"
        unset files
        unset filelist
    fi  
    return
}
```

### The `helperlib.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# File: helperlib.sh 
# Brief: Library for cpRecent, mvRecent commands

# Error codes
no_args="You need to pass in an argument"
invalid_option="Invaild option:"
no_directory="No directory found"

# Return values 
fullpath=
directories=
numfiles=
interactive=

typeset -a files
typeset -A filelist

# Advise that you use relative paths
__returnfullpath(){
    local npath
    if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
        cd "$(dirname $1)"
        npath="$PWD/$(basename $1)"
        npath="$npath/"         #Add a slash
        npath="${npath%.*}"     #Delete . 
    fi
    fullpath=${npath:=""}
}

__usage(){

cat <<End-Of-Message
_______________________________________________________________________________
Copies/Moves the n most recent file(s) in a directory to another directory where
n is user specified. 

<cpRecent/mvRecent> [-d "D1,D2"] [-n NUM] [-ih]

    -d "D1,D2"  The directory that is copied/moved from is D1 while  
            the directory that is copied/moved to is D2 
            The directories would need to be in relative paths
    -n      This specifies an integer num of files 
    -i      This allows the user to edit the name of the file
            to be copied or moved   
    -h      Shows this entire wall of text      

An example of how to use the command:

    cpRecent -d "Documents,." -n 3

    (This means that copy the three(3) most recent files in Documents to 
    the folder I am currently in)
_______________________________________________________________________________
End-Of-Message
}


__processoptions(){
    OPTIND=1
    while getopts ":d:n:ih" opt; do
        case $opt in 
            d ) IFS=',' read -r -a directories <<< "$OPTARG";; 
            n ) numfiles=$OPTARG;;
            i ) interactive=1;;
            h ) __usage; return 1;;
            \? ) echo "$invalid_option -$OPTARG" >&2 ; return 1;;
            : ) echo "$no_args"; __usage >&2 ; return 1;;
            * ) __usage >&2; return 1;;
        esac
    done    
    shift "$((OPTIND-1))"

    # Check for errors  
    (( ${#directories[@]} != 2 )) && echo "$invalid_option Number of directories must be 2" && return 2

    __returnfullpath "${directories[0]}"
    directories[0]="$fullpath"
    __returnfullpath "${directories[1]}"
    directories[1]="$fullpath"  

    if [[ -z ${directories[0]} || -z ${directories[1]} ]]; then
        echo $no_directory 
        return 3
    fi

    [[ numfiles != *[!0-9]* ]] && echo "$invalid_option Number of files cannot be a string" && return 4

    (( $numfiles == 0 )) && echo "$invalid_option Number of files cannot be zero" && return 4

    return 0    
}


__getrecentfiles(){

    local num="-"$numfiles""

    # Get the requested files in directory(skips directories)
    if [[ -n "$(ls -t ${directories[0]} | head $num)" ]]; then
        # For some reason using local -a or declare -a does not seem to split the string into two
        local tempfiles=($(ls -t ${directories[0]} | head $num))
        for index in "${!tempfiles[@]}"; do
            echo $index ${tempfiles[index]}
            [[ -f "${directories[0]}${tempfiles[index]}" ]] && files+=("${tempfiles[index]}") 
        done
    fi

}

__processlines(){
    local name
    local answer
    if [[ -n $interactive ]]; then
        for index in "${!files[@]}"; do
            name=${files[index]}
            read -n 1 -p "Old name: $name. Do you wish to change the name(y/n)?" answer
            # Need to leave a space in between the variables 
            [[ "$answer" == "y" ]] && read -p "Enter new name:" name
            local dirFrom="${directories[0]}${files[index]}"
            local dirTo="${directories[1]}$name"
            filelist+=(["$dirFrom"]="$dirTo")
        done
    else                                    
        for index in "${!files[@]}"; do
            local dirFrom="${directories[0]}${files[index]}"
            local dirTo="${directories[1]}${files[index]}"
            filelist+=(["$dirFrom"]="$dirTo")
        done    
    fi

}
```